# Tables border HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I'm having this weird little problem I can't get my head wrapped around.
What it needs to do is:
table with 3 cells, no/white borders except the top border of all cells and the left and right border of the middle cell.

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
table{
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color:#000000;
    border-right-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-left-color:#FFFFFF;
}

table td.centercell {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-right-color:#000000;
    border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-left-color:#000000;
    z-index:10;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Info Header 1</td>
        <td class="centercell">Info Header 2</td>
        <td>Info Header 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Does anybody have any idea why I can't get it fixed?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? I could tell you that you're writing too much css for this, but i'd like a fiddle to make sure I'm giving you sound advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's the border-collapse on the table that's doing the damage. Obviously you're still going to need that so . . .

Add a border-right to the first cell and only border-right to the second.

```
table td.centercell {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-right-color:#000000;
    z-index:10;
}  
td:first-child{
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/7t85q/

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using #FFFFFF, use transparent

Then set the border-right of the td

```
 td {
     border-right:1px solid #000;
 }
 td:last-of-type {
     border-right 1px solid transparent
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/2F8vF/2/

Even though centercell has it's own class, it's still a table td class as well. So it was grabbing some CSS that you didn't want.

```
table td {
    padding:8px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-bottom:0px;
}

table td.centercell {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```